# Qt connect slot with signal from boost::shared_ptr

Tags: qt, shared-ptr

I have a mainwindow app, when shortcut is triggered, a dialog will popup to show some information, the user may do some configuration in this dialog, then a signal is sent back to the mainwindow, the mainwindow will do some further work. the pseudo code looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::actionConfigure_triggered()
{

    configureDialog = boost::shared_ptr<configure>(new configure(this));
    configureDialog->show();
    connect(configureDialog.get(), SIGNAL(reload()), this, SLOT(clean_reload()));
}
```

but when I triggered this function several times, segmentation fault happens. I use debugger to trace the execution, SIGSEGV received when executing boost::checked_delete function.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance. 
I just want the configure dialog to be created and deleted dynamically, or there are other better ways to implement this?

Comment: I think i don't have to use smart pointer, when the configuration dialog is closed, it should call its destructor, the dynamically allocated memory should be freed at this point, so there will be no memory leak even I triggered this function several times, right?

Comment: Dialogs don't delete themselves on close unless one sets setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your backtrace the bug seems somewhere in destructor of configure and has little to do with the shared_ptr (except that it is the shared_ptr that calls the destructor)
Check if there are double deletes of your object, if yes there is probably some other reference to it which is not a shared_ptr deleteing the object.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I found the problem, you are right, this is not the problem of shared_ptr, when I assign new value to shared_ptr, it will try to free the original memory it pointed to before, this will call the destructor of that class, the bug lies in configureDialog's destructor, it tries to free a pointer that haven't allocate memory yet. I found there is a easy way to the same thing, Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close event, so I can also use this instead of smart pointer to ensure no memory leakage.